# Cant open developer tools in Safari

Tags: macos, safari, developer-tools

[image]

I'm trying to enable Developer menu in Safari, but a checkbox is inactive, are there other approaches to enable developer tools?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

- Go to `˜/Library/Containers/`
- run the command `defaults write  com.apple.Safari.SandboxBroker ShowDevelopMenu -bool true`

You can check the value of that setting with `defaults read com.apple.Safari.SandboxBroker`